# Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, jvm-hotspot

I am getting following error while running the cassandra.

$ *sudo service cassandra start*

$ *cassandra*

**Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: Cannot open file /var/log/cassandra/gc.log due to Permission denied.**

Comment: Simply try changing the permission of /var/log/cassandra/gc.log file to make it user accessible. Execute chmod 755 /var/log/cassandra/gc.log

Comment: I tried above but it's giving an error: **chmod: cannot access '/var/log/cassandra/gc.log': No such file or directory**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have installed the Cassandra using repositories. Cassandra needs a directory to store data and in your case, it cannot create that directories because of permission problems. You have three-way:

1. Become the root user using the command `sudo su` and run the command `cassandra` as the root user. You can issue the command `sudo systemctl enable cassandra.service` to run Cassandra automatically at startup.
2. change the following setting in `cassandra.yaml` file to where the user has permission, like your home directory.

   data_file_directories

   commitlog_directory

   saved_caches_directory
3. add the line `export CASSANDRA_HOME=path/to/cassandra` in user `.bashrc`  file and after that run `source .bashrc` to compile it. This makes Cassandra know the Cassandra install directory and creates the nesseccery folder within that.